# Glassfish 4.1 cluster stop working suddenly

Tags: glassfish-4.1

I have a production environment with a cluster of glassfish (version 4.1) and 2 nodes. Once every 3 or 4 days the web portal is unavailable, without answers. When we try to access the URL, we get no response. It's as if the cluster can no longer control the nodes.

An important fact: When this problem happens and I execute the stop cluster command, the java processes of the nodes do not finish. They run even after the stop-cluster command. It is always necessary to terminate these processes manually by running a kill -9 ID_PROCESS.

What could be causing this problem?

Another fact is that the log shows nothing. The log only shows while the domain is starting. When the application is up, the log stops being displayed showing the following error:
[stack glassfish node 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcMzb.png)